# regular expression that convert html anchor in to wiki anchor syntax

Tags: php, html, regex, wiki, mediawiki

My page contain lots of anchor and i have to put that html in to wiki page .How can i convert anchor into wiki url in php ?

example  : 
`<a href="http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.add.php">add </a>` wiil be `[http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.add.php add]`

Comment: And what about `<a href="javascript:alert('foo')">bar<script>alert('XSS')</script>baz</a>`?

Comment: @Qtax then it will strip.bcaz wiki will not accept this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
echo preg_replace('#<a.+href="(.+?)".*?>\s*(.+?)\s*</a>#', "[$1 $2]",
    '<a href="http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.add.php">add </a>');
```

**output:**

```
[http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.add.php add]
```

Comment: The ? Is not necessary after a *. The * implies optional

Comment: @JustinPihony: It is. To make the `*` non greedy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
<?php

echo $output = preg_replace("/<a\s+href\s*=\s*['\"]?(.+)['\"]?\s*>(.+)<\/a>/",  
    "[$1 $2]",
    "<a href=http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.add.php>add </a>");

?>
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '(' on

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the beginning and ending delimiters, try it now. I tested it with an online checker this time :)

Comment: http://codepad.org/IgFEkU2w i dont want href.and all in anchor href will  be in '' not double quotes

Comment: Sorry forgot about that somehow. This should work now, but I am on mobile and can't double check til later

Comment: My new edits pass your example in codepad.   If quotes happen it will catch them appropriately, if not it doesn't :)